# Efficiently returning the string basis on current datacenter

Tags: java, optimization, enum

We have machine hostname as -

```
dbx111.dc1.host.com
dbx112.dc2.host.com
dcx113.dc3.host.com

dcx115.dev.host.com
```

Here `dc1`, `dc2`, `dc3` and `dev` are our `datacenter` and we will be having only four `datacenter` as of now. And also it might be possible that machine `hostname` can have more dots in between separated by another domain in future.

Now I need to find out which `datacenter` my current machine is in as I will be running below code on the actual machine.

And also I have two flows as of now: `USERFLOW` and `DEVICEFLOW`.

```
public enum FlowTypeEnum {
    USERFLOW, DEVICEFLOW
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

- If my machine is in `DC1` and flow type is `USERFLOW` then I need to return `/test/datacenter/dc1` but if flow type is `DEVICEFLOW` then I need to return `/testdevice/datacenter/dc1`
- But if my machine is in `DC2` and flow type is `USERFLOW` then I need to return `/test/datacenter/dc2` but if flow type is `DEVICEFLOW` then I need to return `/testdevice/datacenter/dc2`.
- And if my machine is in `DC3` and flow type is `USERFLOW` then I need to return `/test/datacenter/dc3` but if flow type is `DEVICEFLOW` then I need to return `/testdevice/datacenter/dc3`.
- But if my machine datacenter is in `DEV`, and flow type is `USERFLOW` then I need to return "/test/datacenter/dc1" but if flow type is `DEVICEFLOW` then I need to return `/testdevice/datacenter/dc1`.

The only difference between `USERFLOW` and `DEVICEFLOW` is - For `USERFLOW`, I need to use `/test` and for `DEVICEFLOW`, I need to use `/testdevice` and other things are same.

`TestingEnum` class -

```
public class TestingDatacenter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String LOCAL_POOK = DatacenterEnum.getOurlocation().toLocalPook(FlowTypeEnum.USERFLOW);
        System.out.println(LOCAL_POOK);
    }
}
```

`DatacenterEnum` class -

```
public enum DatacenterEnum {

DEV, DC1, DC2, DC3;

    public static DatacenterEnum getOurlocation() {
        return ourlocation;
    }

    public static String forCode(int code) {
        return (code >= 0 && code < values().length) ? values()[code].name() : null;
    }

    private static final DatacenterEnum ourlocation = compareLocation();

    private static DatacenterEnum compareLocation() {
        String currenthost = getHostNameOfServer();

        if (currenthost != null) {
            if (isDevMachine(currenthost)) {
                return DC1;
            }

            for (DatacenterEnum dc : values()) {
                String namepart = "." + dc.name().toLowerCase() + ".";
                if (currenthost.indexOf(namepart) >= 0) {
                    return dc;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String toLocalPook(FlowTypeEnum f) {
        String prefix = "";
        // below if else, looks pretty  odd, may be it can be improved better?
        if (f.equals(FlowTypeEnum.DEVICEFLOW)) {
            prefix = "/testdevice";
        } else if (f.equals(FlowTypeEnum.USERFLOW)) {
            prefix = "/test";
        }
        if (this == DEV) {
            return prefix + "/datacenter/dc1";
        }

        return prefix + "/datacenter/" + name().toLowerCase();
    }

    private static final String getHostNameOfServer() {
        try {
            return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName().toLowerCase();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // log an exception
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static boolean isDevMachine(String hostName) {
        return hostName.indexOf("." + DEV.name().toLowerCase() + ".") >= 0;
    }
}
```

I'm opting for code review to see whether there is any better way of doing this. Is there anything which can be simplified and improved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`final` is meaningless on static methods :

```
private static final String getHostNameOfServer() {
```

For the following :

```
// below if else, looks pretty  odd, may be it can be improved better?
if (f.equals(FlowTypeEnum.DEVICEFLOW)) {
    prefix = "/testdevice";
} else if (f.equals(FlowTypeEnum.USERFLOW)) {
    prefix = "/test";
}
```

there are 2 alternatives

1. make a getPrefix() method on FlowTypeEnum, reducing the above code to :

   `prefix = f.getPrefix();`

   FlowTypeEnum could then look like this :

   ```
   public enum FlowTypeEnum {
       USERFLOW("/test"), DEVICEFLOW("/testdevice");

       private final String prefix;

       FlowTypeEnum(String prefix) {
           this.prefix = prefix;
       }

       public String getPrefix() {
           return prefix;
       }
   }
   ```
2. make a map that maps the the FlowTypeEnum instances to a prefix, reducing the above code to :

   `prefix = mapToPrefix.get(f);`

In both cases you might even inline the prefix variable.

Try to make code resistant to likely changes. In this case, server names and paths are likely to change. Pull these from config files.

All these static methods don't seem to be at home on the `DatacenterEnum`, they don't really operate on `DatacenterEnum` instances. Perhaps they need to find a home on a new class, where they can be non static.

It is unwise to hard code the data centers as enum instances. It simply won't scale. Renaming, removing or adding data centers in the field will require a new release.

Use more meaningful names for variables :

- `dc` -> `dataCenter`
- `f` -> `flowType`

Replace this :

```
currenthost.indexOf(namepart) >= 0
```

by the more readable :

```
currenthost.contains(namepart)
```

Comment: Thanks bowmore for the suggestion. I was not able to understand one thing on `FlowTypeEnum` - Can you provide an example how `f.getPrefix()` will work?

Comment: I've added sample code for FlowTypeEnum.

Answer (score 2):

### Some minors things

You variables names do not always follow conventions.

> ```
> private static final DatacenterEnum ourlocation = compareLocation();
> ```

---

Should be `ourLocation`. You need to capitalize the first letter of each word in your varaible name.

> ```
>     } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
>         // log an exception
>     }
> ```

Well you're not logging anything right now, so either you do it or you remove the comment (Nothing to worry, I just hate comments).

---

It's weird to me to have the get method of a variable before the declaration of the variable.

> ```
> public static DatacenterEnum getOurlocation() {
>     return ourlocation;
> }
> ```

I read a class like a book, so when I encounter something like that I always need to stop my flow, find the variable to see is it a private variable, is someone went crazy and it's from another class. The thing is it's not in order.

---

I don't understand this method :

> ```
> public static String forCode(int code) {
>     return (code >= 0 && code < values().length) ? values()[code].name() : null;
> }
> ```

What it's suppose to do ? Get the name of the server or the enum ?